# Split fixed number of rows to columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel which has 750 rows. I want to split it into multiple columns with 15 rows each. For example.. row1 to row15 in column B, row16 to row30 in column C, row31 to row45 in column D...and so on.

Is there any easy/automated way available in excel to do that? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Microsoft-365 then can use [WRAPCOLS()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-wrapcols-function) function

```
=WRAPCOLS(A1:A420,15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If WRAPCOLS doesn't work for you, then you can get the same output using simple index formula too; Paste this formula in B1 cell & drag down & right accordingly as required...

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(A1)*15-15+ROW(A1))
```

Hope this Helps...

[image]